# How to set processor affinity from Batch File for Windows XP?

Tags: windows-xp, batch-file, executable, dos, affinity

I've got a dual processor machine and I would like to launch an executable via a batch file on both processors.

For example:
(1) Launch Notepad.exe on Processor 1, and
(2) Simultaneously, Notepad.exe on Processor 2

Currently, I'm using the following in my batch file, since my executable was "difficult" to launch and needed a return in order to run when launched:
echo.|DoStuff.exe

Thus, I would like to launch it and have it run on each processor.

Thanks for any feedback provided.

P.S. I don't think "start" will work for me since I need to send in the return character to the executable as shown above with echo.

P.S.S. This is for a Windows XP solution. Thanks.

Comment: You may want to reconsider this. In general, the CPU scheduler will make better decisions than you will. We tried this and actually saw a slight performance decrease from just launching two separate programs

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Microsoft's Sysinternal's [psexec](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553.aspx)'s -a flag can set processor affinity on Windows XP:

```
Usage: psexec [\\computer[,computer2[,...] | @file][-u user [-p psswd]][-n s][-l][-s|-e][-x][-i
[session]][-c [-f|-v]][-w directory][-d][-][-a n,n,...] cmd [arguments]
     -a         Separate processors on which the application can run with
                commas where 1 is the lowest numbered CPU. For example,
                to run the application on CPU 2 and CPU 4, enter:
                "-a 2,4"
```

For example:

```
psexec -a 2 cmd /c "echo.|DoStuff.exe"
```

Comment: Will give this a shot tomorrow.

Thanks a ton.

Answer (score 20):

start /affinity 1 notepad.exe

start /affinity 2 notepad.exe

(Windows7 has affinity for the start command, but XP does not. PSexec works though)

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot use start since I need to use echo.|DoStuff.exe, so a return statement is sent into the Executable. Is there way to set the affinity and send in a return statement?

Comment: What if you started a batch file with some affinity with "echo.|DoStuff.exe" in it? Would that pass on the cmd instance's affinity?

Comment: why 0F doesn't use all 4 processors like it was supposed to?

Answer (score 0):

- [This page](http://www.ocforums.com/archive/index.php/t-453554.html) talks about a free
  tool called XCPU you can use to
  launch and set affinity. However the
  link within doesn't work. Maybe a bit
  of googling can locate it for you.
- And there is a simmillar tools
  [here](http://www.activeplus.com/us/freeware/runfirst/) called runfirst.

Comment: it can still be found using archive.org, see http://web.archive.org/web/20071012053544/http://www.appliedvisual.com/xcpu.htm Posting this here since this is one of the higher-ranked Google results, so this can probably still be useful to some.