# Assigning a "system" command to a specific processor in Matlab

Tags: matlab, parallel-processing

I'm using Matlab to run Fortran executable, using the system() command.

Typically I run many runs with the executable.

Is there a way to run say 8 runs of the executable in a designated core?

Or even running simultaneous instances in Matlab? I.e. it would be equivalent to having many cmd windows open.

Many thanks.

Comment: The choice of which core to run a process on is not Matlab's choice, but is buried somewhere deep within the operating system. So if at all possible, you should check this in the context of your operating system rather than in the matlab context.

Comment: Running GNU Linux you can use `taskset [options] <mask> <command>` (part of the util-linux-ng package) to pin your program to a designated core.

Answer (score 0):

Guessing that you're on windows, you can stick to `system()` and modify your system-call appropriately, as described here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/832614/2319400

Answer (score 0):

On Microsoft Windows, you could use [`start`](http://dosprompt.info/commands/start.asp) command to run your programs with the desired processor affinity (these are logical cores, so on my quad-core machine with hyper-threading, I see 8 CPUs). This is specified as a binary mask in hex notation. Examples:

```
>> system('start /affinity 1 notepad')    % (0001) CPU0
>> system('start /affinity 2 notepad')    % (0010) CPU1
>> system('start /affinity 4 notepad')    % (0100) CPU2
>> system('start /affinity 7 notepad')    % (0111) CPU0+CPU1+CPU2
```

Note that by default, `start` will run the program and return immediately. If you want it to hang around until it finishes, you could use `start /wait ...` instead